# Javascript Add delay every 5th time in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I'm using a for loop to go through it like this:

```
var test=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
for(var i=0; i<test.length;i++){
  console.log(test[i]);
}
```

Now I want to know how to set a delay (5 seconds) every 5th item in array looped and then continue through the rest of the array.

Comment: Keep track of the index you're on. Have the loop start on the index you kept track of. Put the loop in a function. Call that function with window.setInterval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually *delay* code in JavaScript (well, not reasonably), but you can schedule it to run later and then let the current task complete. On browsers and in some non-browser environments, that's done with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

In your case, `setTimeout` would probably make the most sense:

```
var test=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
var i =0;
loop();
function loop() {
    var max = Math.min(i + 5, test.length);
    var j;
    for (j = i; j < max; ++j, ++i) {
        console.log(test[j]);
    }

    if (j < test.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 second
    }
}
```

**Live Example:** *(using a shorter delay)*

```js
var test = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13'];
var i = 0;
loop();

function loop() {
  var max = Math.min(i + 5, test.length);
  var j;
  for (j = i; j < max; ++j, ++i) {
    snippet.log(test[j]);
  }

  if (j < test.length) {
    setTimeout(loop, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29900723/390819), but using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do the array math:

```
var test=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];

function processBatchesOfFive() {
  var fiveItemBatch = test.splice(0, 5);

  // process the batch here
  console.log('Now processing: ' + fiveItemBatch);

  if(test.length){
    setTimeout(processBatchesOfFive, 1000); // modify delay here
  }
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsbin.com/nuneyu/1/edit?js,console

*Note: this version mutates the `test` array, so you might want to make a copy of it first.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't pause a loop in Javascript (in any useful manner). Divide the work into showing five items at a time, and use `setTimeout` to start the next part after a delay:

```js
var test = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
var index = 0;
showItems();

function showItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5 && index < test.length; i++, index++){
    console.log(test[index]);
  }
  if (index < test.length) {
    window.setTimeout(showItems, 5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to sleep, and then call it. 
Every 5th element should be a (multiple of 5 -1)
as i starts from 0.

```
var test=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
  for(var i=0; i<test.length;i++){
   if((i+1)%5 == 0)
     sleep(5000);
   console.log(test[i]);
  }

function sleep(miliseconds) {
       var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
       while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
       }
   }
```

Comment: does not work, not sure what you were trying to do there? setTimeout is asynchronous.

Comment: you are using setTimeout wrongly, the first parameter needs to be a function reference, second argument is the amount of time. Plus just calling setTimeout does not pause javascript execution

Comment: Ohh right!
I had forgotten, I think calling a function instead should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Bin: http://jsbin.com/yuheziwozi/1/edit?js,console

```
var test=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
test.forEach(function(num,index){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(num);
    },(parseInt(index/5))*5000);
});
```